# concat sql rows

Tags: mysql, sql, rows, concatenation

Suppose I have this rows in a table

```
hello
guys
how
are
you?
```

My expected result is a single row like this one:

```
hello, guys, how, are, you?
```

What can I do?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As GordonLinoff mentioned in the comment, `GROUP_CONCAT` works.

I don't know your table names or table structures, but you can do something like:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(col_name) FROM table WHERE ...
```

You can read [about it here.](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)

Comment: I just saw @GordonLinoff posted the same thing I did.